# System.MissingMethodException Method 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_Proxy' not found

Tags: xamarin, missingmethodexception

This is a Xamarin solution and I am getting the error found in this message's title. Of course, I can easily confirm that there is a Proxy property on HttpClientHandler in the PCL project. And the solution builds without error. Only when I run does it produce this error (on either Droid or iOS) and does so at the point where it invokes the method in the PCL which instantiates the HttpClient.  Note that it doesn't even get to that method.  The error appears on the application start-up method; e.g., UIApplication.Main()

If I comment out the handler and instantiate HttpClient without a handler, it works fine as long as I'm on the open internet. But I'm trying to get this to work from behind a proxy.

Further investigation showed that the device projects had no references to System.Net.Http. So I added these -- and it indicates Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android as the packages -- but it still produces the error.

I'm not clear what the error is telling me but I believe it means that the device project can't see System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler?

```
    private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyConfig.Url)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ProxyConfig.Username, ProxyConfig.Password)
        };

        // At runtime, when GetHttpClient is invoked, it says it cannot find the Proxy setter
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = proxy,
            UseProxy = true,
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        // This works when not behind a proxy
        //HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        return client;
    }

    public async Task GetWeatherAsync(double longitude, double latitude, string username)
    {

        // MissingMethodException is thrown at this point
        var client = GetHttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://api.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat={0}&lng={1}&username={2}", latitude, longitude, username));

        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherResult>(JsonResult);

                SetValues(weather);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it with an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It could be a mismatch between the dll you are referencing and the actual dll available during runtime, but with code it might be lots easier to track down

Comment: I'll add the code but don't think that will help.  It builds/compiles with out an issue.  All intellisense references are happy.  It is only at runtime, when it goes to invoke the method that instantiates, that it produces the error.  I'm convinced this is some kind of reference issue but just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `Microsoft.Net.Http` [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) to your platform project too. If you run into an issue adding this, try installing the latest `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Build/) first. Then, after that is installed, add the HTTP package.

Comment: That was it.  I had tried adding the Microsoft.Net.Http package before but it responded "Unable to add package".  Subsequently, I had found I had to add the Microsoft.Bcl.Build package to all projects and had did so.  But I'd never gone back and tried the Microsoft.Net.Http package again.  Thanks!

Comment: I've followed these steps but still getting this behaviour. Does it have to be specific versions?

Comment: This also applied when I was getting 'http.httpclienthandler.set_automaticdecompression not found' after setting 'AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip' on HttpClient

Comment: This worked for me .. installing the Microsoft.Net.Http along with microsoft.Bcl.Build, thank you.