# Unable to instantiate new MobileServiceClient in existing Xamarin Forms App

Tags: .net, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I’m just trying to add `MobileServiceClient` functionality into an existing Xamarin Forms App and hitting a brick wall.
As soon as I try an instantiate the `MobileServiceClient` class I get an exception:

> Method 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression'
>   not found.

I’ve tried everything I can find by googling, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289668/system-missingmethodexception-method-system-net-http-httpclienthandler-set-prox) but it hasn’t helped. In fact, I’ve completely uninstalled and reinstalled

```
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.Sqlitestore
Microsoft.BCL
Microsoft. BCL.build
Microsoft.Net.Http
```

From the PCL and platform projects and re-installed them one-by one, making sure that `BCL.Build` and `Microsoft.Net.Http` were last-but-one and last respectively.

In my PCL I can see in packages.config:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
```

And in the Android one for example:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
```

Does anyone know if there’s something else I can try or if I need to set specific versions?

I should also add that I've downloaded the same / quickstart app from the Azure portal and that runs fine, so its project specific.

Looking at the `TargetFrameWorkVerion` and `TargetFrameworkProfile` nodes in the PCL csprj, both the working project and non-working project list

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile259</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

Thanks

Comment: How are your linker settings setup? It might be a too aggresive linker strategy, that are stripping it away from the assembly.

Comment: maybe you have a PCL profile problem.  Did you check the difference with the Azure quick start project?

Comment: @Ulbo: i haven't changed anything and tbh wouldn;t know where to check.

Comment: @hugo: see my edit. Checked the TargetFrameWork elements in the project and they are both the same

Comment: Can you create a github example with your problem?

Comment: How to configure it depends on your IDE. In VS for windows hit the project properties, for the platform project and check the tab called e.g. "iOS build". Try to put your linker bahviour to "Don't link".

Comment: @LDJ did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue.